# Where can I find the source code of Unix utilities?

Tags: linux, gnu-coreutils

Could anyone provide me with the pointers to source code
for linux commands such as 'sort' , 'uniq' etc.?

Comment: google for source code linux shell command.

Comment: @philippe: naturally i had already googled that, ..but the link liw.fi has given doesn't show up(at least on first page of results).

Answer (score 28, accepted):

On Debian and Ubuntu:

```
apt-get source coreutils
```

More generally: http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/

Comment: to jump right into the source browser, go here: http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/tree/

Comment: And for a GitHub mirror: https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils

Answer (score 4):

For sources much closer to the original UNIX toolset (and not the GNU rewrites),

> [The *Heirloom Toolchest*](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/tools.html) is a collection of standard Unix utilities.
>
> Highlights are:
>
> - **Derived from original Unix material** released as Open Source by [Caldera](http://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Caldera-license.pdf) and [Sun](http://www.opensolaris.org/).

Answer (score 2):

Generally on rpm managed Linux distribution, for me to check which file belong to which package, I will use command like:

```
rpm -qf `which sort`
```

Answer (score 1):

From [OpenSolaris](http://src.opensolaris.org/source/xref/onnv/onnv-gate/usr/src/cmd/). IMHO much cleaner code then GNU.

Comment: The opening of OpenSolaris code is actually a large source of the sources collected in the Heirloom tools I linked to in my answer.

Comment: thanks terminus for the soloaris link.
Did you have the chance to review the code in GNU/solaris systems ? i personally intend to learn from them ( as they are widely used stable tools ).